# Entity Framework Core Randomly Getting 'The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.'

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Creating my first full on project with ASP.Net Core and of course using all of the new xxx Core libraries like Entity Framework Core.  Things are going well and I like the Dependency Injection in most areas.  My issue is that I am inconsistently getting the error:

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

```cs
PayPeriod = await (from e in context.Employees
                   join s in context.PayPeriodStyles on e.PayPeriodStyleID equals s.ID
                   join p in context.PayPeriods on s.ID equals p.PayPeriodTypeID
                   where e.ID == employeeID
                   select p)
                   .AsNoTracking()
                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

My code is simple-ish and should not be a problem.  It does not always happen on say the 4th or 6th click but eventually it will happen.  I am trying to find a way around it.  I suppose I could catch it and pass back some failed flag so it will try it again, but that seems kludgey.

While researching this error, it seems everything points to using a `using` statement.  However, while learning ASP.Net Core, from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud), they do not use any `using` statement so why should I.  It seems thanks to DI, that is no longer necessary I guess.

For further insight into the application, my client side is using KnockoutJS.  When the user clicks a calendar day, a method gets called to fill in all of the data of the calendar.  A portion of which is the PayPeriod they currently selected.

So everyone can see the entire process, here are the different code pieces.  I do not think it is anything other than the above.  But I am here asking for help so I want to give everything up front.

**Client Side - Knockout - Starts the process off**

```js
self.BuildAndFillCalendar = function (isInitialCall) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/v1/ProjectTime/BuildAndFillCalendar",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    data: { "givenDate": moment(self.Date()).format("MM-DD-YYYY"), "employeeID": self.EmployeeID }
  }).done(function (result) {
    self.Calendar(new ACalendarModel(result));
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("BuildCalendar Error: " + errorThrown);
  });
};
```

**The MVC Controller catching the above GET request**

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("BuildAndFillCalendar")]
public async Task<IActionResult> BuildAndFillCalendarAsync(DateTime givenDate, int employeeID) {
  ACalendar Result = await Repo.BuildAndFillCalendarAsync(givenDate, employeeID);

  return Ok(Result);
}
```

**The actual logic to make the database calls and put things together**

```cs
public async Task<ACalendar> BuildAndFillCalendarAsync(DateTime givenDate, int employeeID) {
  ACalendar Result = null;

  try {
    // Build the Month for the given date
    await Task.Run(() => {
      Result = new ACalendar(givenDate);
    });

    // Gather the Employees specific Pay Period for the given date
    AlmanacResponse<PayPeriodWindow> CalendarWindow = await GetEmployeePayPeriodWindowAsync(givenDate, employeeID);

    Result.PayPeriod = CalendarWindow.Result;

    // Gather the Employees ProjectTime records for the given visible Month
    var Times = await context.ProjectTimes
      .Include(x => x.Project)
      .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == employeeID && x.Date >= CalendarWindow.Result.FirstDayOnCalendar && x.Date <= CalendarWindow.Result.LastDayOnCalendar)
      .AsNoTracking()
      .ToListAsync();

    // Add the ProjectTime entries to the Calendar
    foreach (var t in Times)
      Result.AddProjectTime(t);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.LogError(1, e, "Unable to build the Employees Project Time Calendar");
  }

  return Result;
}
```

**The sub-call from the previous code set where the error occurs (also first code shown in this question)**

```cs
public async Task<AlmanacResponse<PayPeriodWindow>> GetEmployeePayPeriodWindowAsync(DateTime givenDate, int employeeID) {
  var Result = new AlmanacResponse<PayPeriodWindow>();

  try {
    PayPeriod PayPeriod = await (from e in context.Employees
                                 join s in context.PayPeriodStyles on e.PayPeriodStyleID equals s.ID
                                 join p in context.PayPeriods on s.ID equals p.PayPeriodTypeID
                                 where e.ID == employeeID
                                 select p)
                                 .AsNoTracking()
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    Result.Result = await GetPayPeriodWindow(PayPeriod, givenDate);
    Result.WasSuccessful = true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Result.AddMessage(e, nameof(GetEmployeePayPeriodWindowAsync));
    logger.LogError(1, e, "Unable to gather Employees Pay Period Window");
  }

  return Result;
}
```

**The `PayPeriod` Object**

```cs
public class PayPeriod : AuditableBase {

  public bool IsActive { get; set; }

  public PayPeriodStyle PayPeriodType { get; set; }
  public int PayPeriodTypeID { get; set; }

  public DateTime FirstDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime? SecondDate { get; set; }

  public decimal WorkDayHours { get; set; }
}
```

So, are there certain situations where I should use a `using` statement?  If so, point me to the docs for that.

Is it something to do with my EF configuration?

Is it because the call is originating from AJAX?

Comment: Wow.  I have stumped the community.  This is a first for a question I have written.